# No property like "VersionBuild" in SSRS(.rdl)?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

It seems that SSRS rdl files don't have a property like "VersionBuild" in SSIS dtsx files.

Is there any property like "VersionBuild" for SSRS? If not, could you let us know how you check and control the versions of rdl files?

Comment: did you ever solve this? A version build on SSRS reports would be super useful!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a property or a way of having a version control of the SSRS rdls.

One manual way  (out of the box) is to create a parameter (text type) in the rdl and use it to keep the version number, but you need to update it every time you modify the rdl.

J_P